# how get stars and comments in google map with react native

Tags: google-maps, axios, react-native-maps

i want to get places stars and comments but i dont know how can i get it,
this is my code for photo, name,vicinity but i didnt find stars and comments

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {API_KEY, API_ENDPOINT} from '../../constants';

export default class PlacesItem extends Component {
    render() {
        const {photos} = this.props.item;

        let source;
        if (photos) {
            source = {uri: `${API_ENDPOINT}/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=${photos[0].photo_reference}&key=${API_KEY}`}
        } else {
            source=require('../../assets/nophoto.jpg')
        }

        return (
                <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
                    <Text
                        numberOfLines={1}
                        style={styles.text}>{this.props.item.name}, {this.props.item.vicinity}</Text>
                    <Image
                        style={styles.photo}
                        source={source}/>
                </View>
        )}}
```

Comment: have you considered using [Places details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsRequests) to get the reviews and ratings of a certain place? You just need include the **review** field to get the user's rating and comments about a place. The results of the request look like this: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResponses

Comment: thank you very much, i didnt see this, thanks again

Comment: Glad I could help!